# Nodejitsu says my app is "not a Node app" - Is there a special way to write a node app for Nodejitsu deployment?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, nodejitsu

I've written a node app, which works fine for me locally, but when I try to install it to nodejitsu, I'm given the response:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts>jitsu install index_all.js
info:    Welcome to Nodejitsu jt0dd1995
info:    jitsu v0.13.9, node v0.10.23
info:    It worked if it ends with Nodejitsu ok
info:    Executing command install index_all.js
error:   Sorry, index_all.js is not a node app
error:   Error running command install index_all.js
help:    For help with this error contact Nodejitsu Support:
help:      webchat: <http://webchat.nodejitsu.com/>
help:          irc: <irc://chat.freenode.net/#nodejitsu>
help:        email: <support@nodejitsu.com>
help:
help:      Copy and paste this output to a gist (http://gist.github.com/)
info:    Nodejitsu not ok

C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts>
```

Is there a special way that I need to write a node app for it to work with [nodejitsu](https://webops.nodejitsu.com)?

[Here's the app](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10094515)

Comment: You probably need to have a package.json file in the same directory as your app for the jitsu command line program to determine the name of your app and other properties. http://package.json.nodejitsu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do

```
  jitsu install
```

if u have a `package.json`file that should work